# Dpkg fails to configure package tzdata--how can I fix templatedb?

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg

Another package I'm trying to install depends on the [tzdata](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges) package, which remains unconfigured due to the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure tzdata
Current default time zone: 'America/New_York'
Local time is now:      Fri Feb 10 14:31:37 EST 2017.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Feb 10 19:31:37 UTC 2017.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": rename failed: Is a directory
dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata
```

But, simple as tzdata seems to be, I can't figure out what/where/how `templatedb` is supposed to exist. I tried searching the files brought in with `tzdata` but got nothing:

```
$ sudo dpkg -L tzdata | grep templatedb
$
```

Where can I find `templatedb`, and what is it supposed to be, if not a directory? (Or, more generally, how can I get `tzdata` to configure correctly so I can move on?)

Comment: Template database file is named `template.dat`. It is situated in /var/cache/debconf/ directory. May be there are some problems with access rights. Did you try to set tzdata under root account?

Comment: @OlegBolden Thank you! That helped me figure out what was wrong. I'll post an answer for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Oleg's comment, I found that my `/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat` file was, for some reason, a directory containing a single, empty file: `poll.h`. Not sure what put it there, but it seemed safe to delete, so I did. I then replaced `templates.dat` with `templates.dat-old` (there was also a `templates.dat-new`, neither of which were directories), ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf`, and then `sudo dpkg --configure tzdata`. Everything resolved fine.

This solved my issue, but I'm going to leave the question open in case someone else wants to give a more thorough explanation, since I don't really understand completely what all was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it can be a problem with `debconf` package

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```